# How to make canvas full width and height of body while not stretching or blurring drawings?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make a canvas that occupies the full width and height of the body (with no scrolling), and has non stretched and non blurred drawings. Whenever I make a canvas 100vw and 100vh, the drawings get blurred and stretched image, with incorrect sizings.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="c" style="border: 2px solid black;"></canvas>
<style> body, html {padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;} </style>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function draw() {
ctx.fillRect(100, 50, 100, 75);
c.style.width = document.body.clientWidth;
c.style.height = document.body.clientHeight;
}
draw();
</script>
```

This code produces a black rectangle, but very blurry and a much larger size then I would like and expect (considering the width and height of the canvas is the whole body, and the width and height of the rectangle is only 100 and 75). Are there any fixes to this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is because you are assigning the height after you the rectangle. Either try putting the two sequences that set the size of the canvas before `ctx.fillRect()` or set the actual height of the canvas on the html element `<canvas height="100%" width="100%">`. Tell me how that goes

Comment: Would this work if I styled the canvas with 100vw and 100vh?

Comment: Perhaps, the reason why it is getting stretched is because you draw the rectangle before you set the size, as long as you set the size before drawing anything on your canvas it shouldnt be stretched etc.

Comment: Also, when I change the width and height to 100vw and 100vh, the canvas auto resizes to about 100 x 100. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe you are setting it incorrectly? Im not sure never really worked with the units vh and vw

Comment: Setting `canvas.width = window.innerWidth;` and  `canvas.height = window.innerHeight` I don't seem to get any blurring or stretching

Comment: @Ameer this works the same as Sean's answer, thanks. But is there any way to make the drawing even more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it gets stretched etc. is because of several reasons:

- The rectangle must be drawn after the size of the canvas is set
- When setting the canvas size, you don't actually set the style height and width, since the element canvas already has those attributes itself.

  Also note that you will want your body/html css height to be 100% since it begins as auto, when canvas' height is set to the height of the body, it only fills up the little space body initially gives it compared to the whole screen.

Your new `draw()` function should look like this

```js
function draw() {
c.width = document.body.clientWidth; // Remove .style from both
c.height = document.body.clientHeight;
ctx.fillRect(100, 50, 100, 75); // fillRect post setting size
}
```

and css

```css
<style> body, html {padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; height:100%;} </style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works! Just wondering, is there any way to make the drawing a little more clear? I'll mark this as an answer but please respond :)

Comment: That's about as clear as it gets, it may just seem a bit blurry due to size? There may be another graphics library like OpenGL that will result with a more crisp display but that framework will have a complete different setup compared to HTML's Canvas

Comment: Thank you, this was very informative and helpful. +1 and marked as answer!